# Can you mix UIModalPresentationCurrentContext and a custom transition?

Tags: uikit, modalviewcontroller, custom-transition

I have an app with a user interface that contains two items, each of which is its own view controller. When you decide to change one of the items, I use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` with `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` to modally present a picker over just the item you're changing. Since the view controller is set to define a presentation context, this ensures not only that the picker covers only that view controller, but also that its `presentingViewController` is the one for that item, so the unwind segue triggered by picking an item passes through that view controller too, changing the item.

This works beautifully, except that I want to do it with a custom (and hopefully interactive) transition. To accomplish that, I tried to set the picker's `transitioningDelegate` to a custom object implementing `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`. However, the `transitioningDelegate` is ignored unless you use `UIModalPresentationCustom`, which ignores `definesPresentationContext` and presents from the root view controller, thus breaking this whole arrangement.

Is there some way to present a modal view controller with a custom transition that respects presentation contexts? Or am I going to have to find another way to do this?

Comment: @fbeeper Nope, sadly.

Comment: Have you tried UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContex? I haven't investigated much, but a quick test of your situation with this new iOS 8 mode made an existing animation work just fine :)